# Unable to delete process from processbuilder

Tags: process-builder

We have a process which has scheduled action. We have changed our design and that process is no longer needed I am unable to delete it after deactivation. How do I delete/see the pending task like I can see for time dependent workflow

Comment: Can you paste the error

Comment: see this https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_limits_scheduled.htm&language=en_US&type=0

Answer (score 1):

Actions queued by the Processes comes under this - got this from [here](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000D4T9AAK) once I deleted those pending action I am able to delete the process.

[image]